# Can I keep all Flask blueprints in one file?

Tags: python, flask

I am using an app factory to initialize my app.  In it, I import all the blueprints and register them one by one.  Is there a way I can move the import and register statements to a different file or inform the factory about them without referencing them all individually?

```
def create_app(config_filename):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config_filename)

    from app.users.models import db
    db.init_app(app)

    from app.users.views import users
    from app.posts.views import posts
    app.register_blueprint(posts, url_prefix='/posts')
    app.register_blueprint(users, url_prefix='/users')

    return app
```

In my project I'm actually generating the blueprints with another script, so I'd like to be able to generate the registration too by appending to a file or something, rather than trying to modify code in the factory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can import and register the blueprints in some other module.  But there's no practical point to this approach, it just moves the imports and register calls somewhere else.

`myapp/blueprints.py`:

```
from app.users.views import users
from app.posts.views import posts

def init_app(app):
    app.register_blueprint(users, prefix='/users')
    app.register_blueprint(posts, prefix='/posts')
```

`myapp/__init__.py`:

```
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    # ...
    from myapp import blueprints
    blueprints.init_app(app)
    # ...
```

---

Something more useful might be to tell the app what packages to import from and have the app expect to find a blueprint in some standard location for each package.  Assuming the blueprint variable will always have the same name as the package, is defined in `views`, and has the same prefix as the name:

```
from werkzeug.utils import import_string

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    # ...
    for name in ('users', 'posts'):
        bp = import_string('myapp.{0}.views:{1}'.format(name, name))
        app.register_blueprint(bp, prefix='/{0}'.format(name))
    # ...
```